# AdvancedDatagrid column Itemeditor and issues with setting dataprovider value

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, flex3

I have an editable advanceddatagrid (editable column). I am providing the arraycollection as a dataprovider. (fname(string), lname(string), bdate(Date)). (3 columns)

I have created the VO for fname, lname, and bdate. Whenever I edit bdate and focus out , it will try to get saved the string value as a Date and got failed (which is obvious). By default, editor consider "TextInput" as an itemeditor and save the inserted date as a text and that text value getting refused by the VO which is expecting behavior.

1. I tried to update the value in "ItemEditEnd" event handler but it wont allow me to do that.
2. I also tried to put a check at VO but it never reached there. (I am not sure why)

I have to strictly keep the VO as Date instead of text.

Is there anyway we can convert string into Date ? Any other place ? Is there anything I can do at collection change ?

Please help me if possible.

thanks,

Comment: Ans : editorDataField : This could be the helpful property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I would use another approach than the one you are suggesting.

```
<s:GridColumn headerText="Birth Date" dataField="bdate" rendererIsEditable="true">
     <s:itemRenderer>
         <fx:Component>
             <s:GridItemRenderer>
                 <mx:DateField selectedDate="@{data.bdate}"/>
             </s:GridItemRenderer>
         </fx:Component>
     </s:itemRenderer>
 </s:GridColumn>
```

In this example I am using an ItemRenderer which will also function as the ItemEditor.
In this case it is a DateField, which will be able to cope with the date property you have in your VO without the need to be [parsing dates manually](http://blog.flexmp.com/2008/04/08/datefield-itemeditor-when-date-is-a-string/).

Suggested for you to read up:

- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemeditors_pt1.html
- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_3.html

Comment: This would be helpful in case of rendererIsEditable="true" but in my case I cant show the datechooser all the time as its not the part of design and it will occupy the space for that perticular grid cell. Otherwise, your answer is acceptable. Thanks.